# I'm trying to Rename a File using Java But It is Not Working for Some Reason

Tags: java, file, boolean, filepath, file-rename

```
File oldfile = new File("C:\\NewText Document.txt");
File newfile = new File("C:\\Hello Buddy.txt");

if (oldfile.renameTo(newfile))
{
   System.out.println("Rename succesful");
}
else
{
   System.out.println("Rename failed");
}
```

I'm planning on developing it into a file normalizer, but I just want to get this done first.
I've tried using the absolute path, makes no difference. Constantly returning "Rename Failed".

Comment: Does the file actually exist? Do you have write access to `C:\\`?

Comment: Indeed, what does oldfile.isFile() return? or exists()? And there is no "hello buddy.txt" yet, right? And your user has the rights to rename files in c:\?

Comment: This is a known issue. See e.g:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000183/reliable-file-renameto-alternative-on-windows
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826045/file-renameto-fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileChooser();
        File oldfile = new File(fileName);

```
    File newfile = new File(fileName.substring(0, 21) + "hello world.txt");
    if (!oldfile.exists())
    {
        try
        {
            oldfile.createNewFile();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
    else
    {

        if (oldfile.renameTo(newfile))
        {

            System.out.println("Rename succesful");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Rename failed");
        }
    }
```

This is my new code, it works using a file chooser,but currently it only works if i choose the file from my desktop, hence the hardcoded substring.

Answer (score 1):

Use move method of Files class. Worked for me ;)

[Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...))

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 7 then try this:

```
    final File oldfile = new File("C:\\NewText Document.txt");
    final File newfile = new File("C:\\Hello Buddy.txt");

    final Path source = oldfile.toPath();
    final Path dest=newfile.toPath();

    try {
         Files.move(source, dest);
    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```