# How to replace a string from multiple folder names inside a directory in windows using Java

Tags: java

I was just trying to rename multiple folders inside a single directory. I thought of using Java code or perl script. but unfortunately I was only able to replace the string for only file names and not for folder names.

If anyone has done this earlier, please share the knowledge.

Example: I have below folders in a directory D:\MyDirectory\
Folder_is_A1
Folder_is_B1
Folder_is_C1
.
.
Folder_is_Z10

I'm trying to rename them as

Folder_A1
Folder_B1
.
.
Folder_Z10

Here is the code which I'm trying.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RenameFoldersInDirectory{

public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the directory path");
        String directoryPath = scanner.nextLine();
        File directory = new File(directoryPath);
        if (!directory.isDirectory()) {
          System.err.println("There is no directory in the path given");
          System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Enter new name of folder");
        String newDirectoryName = scanner.nextLine();
        File newDirectory = new File(directory.getParent() + "\\" + newDirectoryName);
        directory.renameTo(newDirectory);
        System.out.println("Done");


    }

}
```

Comment: Any code to show for? Might help.

Comment: Edited the question with code.Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged "perl"?

Comment: My bad. untagged now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File.renameTo() fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826045/file-renameto-fails)

Comment: PowerShell is probably the easiest way to do this. Example: http://www.lazywinadmin.com/2013/10/powershell-renaming-bunch-of-folders.html

Comment: @jpmc26 - Thanks, will try that!

Comment: @jpmc26 - Just WoW, It worked like a charm! Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: Take it as a lesson in "right tool for the job." PowerShell is *designed* with managing a Windows system in mind. It also has the huge advantage of not requiring compiling a source file, which is ideal for one off things like this. bash would be a much better fit for a Linux system.

Comment: Yeah, definitely a lesson.Thanks!